# Reducing size of an array (by creating a new one) - how does arrayList do it?

Tags: java, android, arrays, arraylist

In one of my classes, I have a method like so:

```
public void setArray(int size){

myArray = new int[size]  //myArray is declared already

}
```

Now, if I call this and pass in, say, 500 like so:

```
setArray(500);
```

And then, later on in my app, I need only an array with, say 50 elements, at the moment, I simply call it again and pass in 50 as my argument.

This array is referenced many times within my app and I'm wondering if the CG will collect the old one?

I know I should really use an arrayList, unfortunately, this would be a major undertaking as my code is now thousands of lines and 18 classes in size (so I guess I've learned for my next project!)

How does arrayList achieve this 'behind the scenes'?  Can I emulate the arrayList behavour?  Does it simply create a new array like I've done?

Comment: Looking at the [source](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/ArrayList.java.html) could be helpful. You might also want to read more about [dynamic arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_array) in general.

Comment: I would definitely recommend you to cover my [Internal life of ArrayList](http://volodial.blogspot.com/2013/07/internal-life-of-arraylist-in-java.html) tutorial. In short to enlarge backing array you use method ensureCapacity. But to eliminate empty buckets at the tail you use trimToSize method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read the source for ArrayList here: [SOURCE](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/ArrayList.java)

And you are right, it keeps an array and replaces it as needed to allow room for more objects. But it also stores the length so the array can be longer than is needed. That allows the ArrayList to grow a little without having to re-create the actual array everytime. If the ArrayList gets smaller, it doesn't have to re-create. It just changes the length as stored.

You can read the code to see how they decide when to change the array itself. Whenever they do that, they have to copy the old one's contents over.

You are right, BTW, that the old arrays get garbage collected as long as there are not variables referencing them. It sort of depends on how your code works. If that code you show and the definition is the only reference, then it will get GC'ed when you make a new array and store it.

Comment: Thanks @Lee Meador - I have a question regarding the GC behaviour in this case, but I will put that into another question - cheers.

Answer (score 4):

You are describing the behavior of a **[dynamic array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_array)**.

The easiest way to implement this data structure is to create a new array once the array is full or below some threshold (only 1/4 of the cells are occupied, for example), and copy existing values into the new array.

If you want to know how it is done in java, and what optimizations are being made - you might want to have a look on the [`ArrayList` class source](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/ArrayList.java.html).

Answer (score 0):

The official implementation of ArrayList never reduces the size of an array, only increases the capacity when needed.
When an element is removed from the ArrayList, it ensures that the posterior elements return one position and sets null for the free element on the right.